# Read string, integers and bytes from file

Tags: go

I have to read a PPM file with its data encrypted (metadata is not encrypted), using Go, and the file format is given to me containing:

- The "P3" magic number (read as string)
- Image width (read as integer)
- Image height (read as integer)
- Maximum color value (read as integer)

Then, I need to read the rest of the file is the encrypted bits, which I have to read as a single byte array/slice.

e.g.:

```
P6
480 360
255
�š��GHFHFI�GHFHFG~EG~EG~E
...
HFD{BR�Rz�y|�vxyyhlf%8&NFzx
```

What is a good way to read string and integers (the 4 initial metadata values) and the rest (encrypted part) as bytes from the file? It can be the most efficient, but the cleanest (less lines) is preferred.

Comment: Are the integers in a string representation, or are they binary? What size are they, or how are they delimited? If they're binary, are the big endian and little endian?

Comment: I think the guys from spakin/netpbm have a pretty neat way of extracting the metadata part for netpbm files using bufio (see their [github-repo](https://github.com/spakin/netpbm/blob/master/netpbm.go))

Comment: @JimB the example I gave is extracted from a real file. The metadata is as written in the example, "P6\n480 360\n255\n", and the rest (data) is just bytes. It's all encoded in utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bufio.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) to read the first 3 lines using the [ReadLine](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine) or [ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) method and reading the rest of the file using the [Read](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) method.

After you've read the first 3 lines you can use the [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package to split the second line, and then the [strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) package to parse the strings containing numbers as integers.

For example:

```
r := bufio.NewReader(file)
line1, err := r.ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// repeat to read line 2 and 3

size := strings.Split(line2, " ")
width, err := strconv.Atoi(size[0])
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
height, err := strconv.Atoi(size[1])
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// repeat with line 3
```

**Update**:

As mentioned in the comments by [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) you can use [bufio.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) together with the [bufio.ScanWord](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanWords) `SplitFunc` to scan for the metadata.

```
s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

var count int
for s.Scan() && count < 4 {
    switch count {
    case 0:
        magic = s.Text()
    case 1:
        if width, err = strconv.Atoi(s.Text()); err != nil {
            return
        }
    case 2:
        if height, err = strconv.Atoi(s.Text()); err != nil {
            return
        }
    case 3:
        if color, err = strconv.Atoi(s.Text()); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    count++
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-rOJb_WlFf

Comment: I tried this approach before, but the problem is: in the PPM file format, any whitespace can be used between the metadata themselves and between metadata and image data.

All the metadata can be written in a single line ("P3 480 360 255") or any combination of whitespaces, not necessarily newline, and I'd like to cover all cases.

Comment: A Scanner would provide the flexibility you need if the delimiters are not consistent: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner

Comment: @GabrielCalixto I've added an example using `bufio.Scanner` as pointed out by @Adrian.

Comment: Thanks, guys!
Actually, I need to read the first 4 infos as 1 string and 3 integers, which the current answer does, but I also need to read the rest of the file (the image pixel data) as a single byte array/slice, or maybe read byte per byte.
In addition, I cannot ignore whitespace included in the pixel data, since it may be an encrypted byte, so I need to read **every** byte after the first 4 symbols, I cannot split all the file in lines or words, since it'll remove the whitespace included in the data.